# Intellij 13 ADB not responding Mac

Tags: android, macos, intellij-idea

After adding the Support-Library ADB won't rspond and I cannot run any emulator. 
I already tried the restarting thing, also the kill-commands on the terminal. Even reinstalling Android SDK. Nothing worked.

Is there anyone with an idea what else I can try or what is going wrong?

Comment: You could try upgrading Intellij. Version 13 is a little old

Comment: The newest verstion doesn't work. It instantly throws an error after starting.